# kivy / buildozer fails with "Please report issue to enable support for newer NDK"

Tags: python, linux, android-ndk, kivy

Ubuntu 13.04

I try to build an apk with `buildozer --verbose android debug deploy run`

I tried with ndk-8e, and then downgraded to ndk-8d, to no avail

```
buildozer --verbose android debug deploy run
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Run 'dpkg --version'
# Cwd None
Programme « dpkg » de gestion de paquets Debian version 1.16.10 (i386).
Ce programme est un logiciel libre ; veuillez consulter la « GNU General
Public License » version 2 ou supérieure pour prendre connaissance des
conditions de reproduction. AUCUNE garantie n'est offerte.
# Search for Git git
#  -> found at /usr/bin/git
# Search for Cython cython
#  -> found at /usr/local/bin/cython
# Search for Java compiler
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/bin/javac
# Search for Java keytool
#  -> found at /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre/bin/keytool
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.8.4
# Android SDK found at /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
# Android NDK is missing, downloading
# Downloading http://dl.google.com/android/ndk/android-ndk-r8d-linux-x86.tar.bz2
# Unpacking Android NDK
# Run 'tar xjf android-ndk-r8d-linux-x86.tar.bz2'
# Cwd /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform
# Rename /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r8d to /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-8d
# Android NDK installation done.
# Android packages already installed.
# Check application requirements
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/gg/kivy2/v3/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Available modules: android audiostream cymunk docutils ffmpeg gevent greenlet hostpython jpeg kivy libevent libxml2 libxslt lxml msgpack mysql_connector numpy openssl paramiko pil plyer png pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python sdl     setuptools sqlalchemy sqlite3 twisted txws wokkel zope
# Application requirements already installed, pass
# Compile platform
# Run './distribute.sh -l'
# Cwd /home/gg/kivy2/v3/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Available modules: android audiostream cymunk docutils ffmpeg gevent greenlet hostpython    jpeg kivy libevent libxml2 libxslt lxml msgpack mysql_connector numpy openssl paramiko pil   plyer png pyasn1 pycrypto pygame pyjnius pylibpd pyopenssl pyparsing pyqrcode python sdl     setuptools sqlalchemy sqlite3 twisted txws wokkel zope
# Run 'git clean -dxf'
# Cwd /home/gg/kivy2/v3/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Removing .packages/
Removing build/
Removing dist/
Removing src/default.properties 
Removing src/local.properties
# Run './distribute.sh -m "kivy"'
# Cwd /home/gg/kivy2/v3/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android
Check build dependencies for Ubuntu
Check enviromnent
SDK located at /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
NDK located at /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-8d
NDK version is 8d
API level set to 14
Check mandatory tools
Distribution will be located at /home/gg/kivy2/v3/.buildozer/android/platform/python-  for-     android/dist/default
Entering in ARM enviromnent
Error: Please report issue to enable support for newer ndk.
# Command failed: ./distribute.sh -m "kivy"
```

Edit: after re-installing buildozer, I go further, but it eventually fails

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.8.4
# Android SDK found at /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
# Android NDK found at /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9
# Android packages already installed.
# Check application requirements
# Compile platform
# Distribution already compiled, pass.
# Build the application #2
# Package the application
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 5, in <module>
run()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1168, in run
Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 814, in  run_command
self.target.run_commands(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 85, in run_commands
func(args)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/target.py", line 97, in cmd_debug
self.buildozer.build()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 172, in build
self.target.build_package()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/targets/android.py", line 385, in  build_package
version = self.buildozer.get_version()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 523, in get_version
with open(fn) as fd:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './main.py'
```

Comment: Has buildozer worked for you in the past? Also, how did you install it, and when did you last update? There have been some recent fixes relating to ndk versions. If you haven't already, you could try uninstalling your current version and download/installing/using the master branch from https://github.com/kivy/buildozer

Comment: Buildozer has never worked for me. I installed with pip or easy_intall. I never updated it. I will try to unistall it and put the master branch. Thanks.

Comment: I notice it now uses android ndk r9 instead of 8e and 8d in my previous tries

Comment: I do not have a file called main.py, is that mandatory?

Comment: Yes, it is mandatory. This file is called to start your app.

Comment: I now get                                                                   Exception: Unable to find capture version in ./main.py
 (looking for `__version__ = '(.*)'`)

Comment: I will proudly add                                                and retry

Answer (score 1):

And I now have my apk, many thanks to inclement for his help!

```
buildozer android debug deploy run
# Check configuration tokens
# Ensure build layout
# Check configuration tokens
# Preparing build
# Check requirements for android
# Install platform
# Apache ANT found at /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.8.4
# Android SDK found at /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-21
# Android NDK found at /home/gg/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r9
# Android packages already installed.
# Check application requirements
# Compile platform
# Distribution already compiled, pass.
# Build the application #2
# Package the application
# Android packaging done!
# APK MyApplication-0.1-debug.apk available in the bin directory
# Deploy on 0123456789ABCDEF
# Application pushed.
# Run on 0123456789ABCDEF
# Application started.
```

Comment: I guess you sorted the `__version__` thing then? For the benefit of anyone else reading, the problem is that buildozer automatically checks main.py for a line like `__version__ = 'some_version_number'`, but gives an error if this doesn't exist. You can solve the problem by creating that line, or by editing buildozer.spec to comment out the version code and uncomment the alternative version method (this is described in the buildozer.spec file).

Comment: `ls -alrt bin
    total 6476
    drwxrwxr-x 4 gg gg    4096 oct.  31 13:31 ..
    drwxrwxr-x 2 gg gg    4096 oct.  31 13:32 .
    -rw-rw-r-- 1 gg gg 6621208 oct.  31 13:32 MyApplication-0.1- debug.apk`

Comment: Yes I sorted it out, with a line stating I had a version 0.1, I will have a look at the buildozer.spec file. Thanks for your help.